# Get class membership output in R package lcmm

Tags: r, mixed-models

I'm playing around with learning the lcmm package.  I ran the following code and received a good fit for three latent classes:

```
ext2<-lcmm(Startle~Trial,random=~Trial,subject='StudyID', 
           mixture=~Trial,ng=3,idiag=TRUE,data=ext,link="5-quant-splines")
```

Now I want to know which of my subjects were included in which latent class.  The R documentation alludes to being able to access this information with pred and predRE, but I can't figure out how to call that information.  Can somebody help me out real quick?  Or does this even make sense to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I see no functions in the help page named 'pred' or 'predRE'. Generally package authors name their functions 'predict' as _is_ the case with `pkg:lcmm`. They have just added a bunch of suffixes to 'predict'. Try looking at `help(package='lcmm')`

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I figured it out.  For anyone's future reference, the command to get the class memberships for the model above is ext2$pprob.